# Not getting the result that I need by using ROW_NUMBER()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using advantureworks2017 and what I'm trying to get is the top 2 selling products by year,, what I have so far is this but it's showing me only the top 2 rows which is not what I need, I need the top 2 products in each year.

```
SELECT  TOP (2) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sum(linetotal) DESC) ,
        ProductID,
        year(h.OrderDate) 'OrderYear'
from    Sales.SalesOrderDetail so
left outer join Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
on  so.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
group by    year(h.OrderDate), ProductID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `row_number` in the subquery and then use that `rank <= 2` in the outer query to select `top 2`

```
select
  ProductID,
  OrderYear
from
(
  SELECT 
          ProductID,
          year(h.OrderDate) 'OrderYear',
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sum(linetotal) DESC)  as rnk
  from    Sales.SalesOrderDetail so
  left outer join Sales.SalesOrderHeader h
  on  so.SalesOrderID = h.SalesOrderID
  group by    year(h.OrderDate), ProductID
) val

where rnk <= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `ORDER` your `ROW_NUMBER` by `sum(linetotal)` it's goning to fail if you have multiple `sum(linetotal)` which are equal.

I prefer to do it that way:

Declare table(number of columns = number of your query results columns + 1)
fill first column in declared table with identity(1,1) and next insert query results into the rest columns.